# NTE941M non-inverting opamp has non-zero output with 0V input

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I have a non-inverting, single-supply, variable gain op-amp circuit configured in accordance with this diagram:

[image: non-inverting opamp]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp15.gif))</sub>

- Vcc: +16V
- \$R_f = 800\text{ k}\Omega\$ Potentiometer
- \$R_2 = 100\text{ k}\Omega\$

I have the potentiometer set to \$\approx 200\text{ k}\Omega\$ for a gain of:

$$
A=(1+R_f/R_2)=(1+200k/100k)=3
$$

I have confirmed that this works experimentally (A=3.07). However, what puzzles me is that when \$V_{\text{in}}\$ is left floating I get an output of 6V instead of approx. 0V. Consequently, any input below approx. 2V yields no change in output.

Per the [datasheet](https://www.nteinc.com/specs/900to999/pdf/nte941m.pdf) for this op amp, the maximum \$V_{\text{os}}\$ is 5mV, which even when amplified by 3, is nowhere near 6V.

Below is a drawing of my circuit:

[image]

Comment: The op amp is only specified for dual voltage operation. How are you providing the bias voltage for the inputs with a single supply? With the input floating, there is no path for the op amp bias current.  Thus the output cannot be determined. Note that a floating input is not the same as a 0 volt input. You need to provide a complete circuit so that we can better comment on its operation.

Comment: @Barry Thank you for the reply. I did not know that this opamp was dual supply only. Would a dual-supply allow the output to "rest" at 0V? For the bias current, I think I understand what you mean because the way that I tested the gain was by connecting points a and b together which would provide current to the non-inverting input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracts from the NTE941M data sheet: -

- Common Mode Input Voltage Range is typically ±12 V on a ±15 V supply.

*This means that if one supply of the op-amp is ground (0 volts) then you must have your input signal greater than typically 3 volts above ground or all bets are off.*

- Output Voltage Swing (for RL ≥ 10kΩ) is typically ±14 V on a ±15 V supply.

*This means that you cannot expect the output to get any closer to the 0 volt rail than typically +1 volt above it.*

> any input below approx. 2V yields no change in output

Do you understand why now?

Comment: I think so. I'm going to need a more precise amp that gets closer to the 0V rail.

Comment: @user3578834 you will find quite a few op-amps that can have their inputs work below the negative rail but you won't find any op-amps whose output goes below the negative rail and it usually falls short by a few tens of millivolts and even more when loaded.